# JQuery document ready not running commands as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug

Please take a look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n44Xt/1/),

And the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("helloo");

    $("#test_div").click(function(){
        console.log("test clicked");
        $("#test").text("Changed");
    });
});
```

The problem is, none of the `console.log(...)` calls seem to be running. I am particularly bothered by the fact that the first one isn't running.

Comment: Have you included jQuery before the document.ready, right?

Comment: what browser are you running this in?

Comment: Works just how it should here. See the first `console.log` on load and an additional for each click.

Comment: Are you looking in the console that is different from the DOM, right?

Comment: Works for me too in Chrome 27 and your code looks fine. What browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox, and yes, JQuery is included.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa I'm looking at the Firebug console.

Comment: @roasted This is just a test. I want to find out why the `console.log` calls are not showing.

Comment: Odd, it seems to be working fine in the built-in Firefox debugger, but not Firebug.

Comment: Seems to be a Firebug bug.

Comment: @Sumurai8 Yes ... how odd.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469340/firebug-problem-cant-use-console-log)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a conflict between Firebug and jsFiddle. To see your `console.log()` output, you can use a different browser such as Chrome, or you can include Firebug Lite in your page, as in this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geary/n44Xt/5/).